# What is the BATCH code counting down 10 seconds until hidbernation?

Tags: batch-file

I have shutdown /h but I dont know how to make a timer so it will do that in a certain amount of seconds! Thanks!

Comment: `/t 10` Do you know Google? https://www.google.fr/search?q=help+shutdown.exe&oq=help+shutdown.exe&aqs=chrome..69i57&client=chrome-mobile&sourceid=chrome-mobile&espvd=1&ie=UTF-8

Comment: `shutdown /?` reveals a `/t` switch